# What article reported variability in supporting hypotheses across disciplines?

Tags: reference-request

I recently read a blog post talking about a journal article that compared the degree to which journal articles support their hypothesis. A comparison was done across disciplines, and if I recall, psychology had a higher level of acceptance than many other disciplines.

- Does anyone know the reference to this article about variability in supporting hypotheses in journal articles across disciplines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fanelli D (2010) “Positive” Results Increase Down the Hierarchy of the Sciences. PLoS ONE 5(4): e10068. doi:10.1371/journal.pone.0010068

http://www.plosone.org/article/info:doi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0010068

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @Xurtio for letting me know the article.

For sake of completeness, the following shows the graph of interest:

[image]

> Name of discipline, abbreviation used throughout the paper, sample
>   size and percentage of “positive” results (i.e. papers that support a
>   tested hypothesis). Classification by discipline was based on the
>   Essential Science Indicators database, the hard/soft, pure/applied and
>   life/non-life categories were based on previous literature (see text
>   for details). Error bars represent 95% logit-derived confidence
>   interval.

Comment: why not just edit the figure into @Xurtio's answer?

Comment: I didn't want to presume that Xurtio would be comfortable with me doing this. I often find it useful to do the above when I get a short answer, but I think that a reader would be interested in a little more information (e.g., on stackoverflow someone gives you a clue about the answer or says what function to apply; but then you go ahead and apply it to your code and show the worked example, etc.)